# Why energy eigenvalues of a one dimensional quantum charged harmonic oscillator in an external electric field decreases?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, electric-fields, schroedinger-equation, harmonic-oscillator

Consider a charged particle in the one-dimensional harmonic oscillator potential. Suppose an electric field of magnitude $E$ is applied along positive $x$ axis, so that the potential energy is shifted by an amount $-qEx$.

By solving the Schrodinger time independent equation we can find energy eigenvalues:

$$E = \hbar \omega \bigg( n+ \frac{1}{2} \bigg) - \frac{q^2 E^2}{2m \omega^2}\quad .$$

The energy eigen values without the external electric field are:

$$E = \hbar \omega \bigg( n+ \frac{1}{2} \bigg) \quad .$$

It is interesting to observe whether the electric field is applied along the positive $x$-axis or the negative $x$-axis, and whether we have a positive charged oscillator or a negative charged oscillator. Surprisingly, the expression for the energy eigenvalues remains the same, meaning that the energy eigenvalues always decrease in comparison to the case when there is no electric field.

My question is: How can we interpret this decrease in energy eigenvalues physically?

Does the total energy of a classical charged harmonic oscillator in an external electric field also decrease irrespective of the nature of charge and the direction of the electric field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider what happens when we add a linear term to a parabola
$$
x^2 + ax = \left(x +\frac{a}{2}\right)^2 - \frac{a^2}{4}
$$
The results is a parabola the same shape as the original one, but shifted down and to one side. To understand why the shift is always down, regardless of the sign of $a$, consider standing at the original minimum value. Since the $x^2$ term is flat here, I should be able to achieve a lower value if I move in the direction that reduces the linear term, so the linear term will always reduce the minimum value.

For a different perspective, the original parabola was symmetric about $x=0$ so there is no reason for a left shift to raise or lower the minimum more than a right shift.

Notice that I have not mentioned potentials, much less quantum or classical systems, only parabola up to this point. These observations, therefore, should be general

Comment: Thank you. Everything makes sense now.